# Merge two tables into one

Tags: sql, merge

I am trying to merge two tables but I'm new to the merge function

**ppltr**

```
pltr_seqn_num    pltr_user     
1              
2              
3              
4                       Chris
```

**poant**

```
poat_pltr_seqn_num      poat_user

2                       Sam 
3                       Dave
4                       Chris

merge into ppltr a
using poant b
on (a.pltr_seqn_num=b.poat_pltr_seqn_num)
when not matched then insert(a.pltr_user) values (b.poat_user)
```

I want ppltr to have all the username values from poant using merge, can anyone advise on how I can get this done?

Comment: Please provide the table structures and format the question

Comment: ppltr has 62 columns,  and poant has 82 colums. I want to merge poant to ppltr, both tables have the same invoice numbers, sequence number but ppltr is missing usernames. I want to merge both tables. I want all the records from poant (over 20000 records) merged into ppltranln. However ppltr may already have those records. I hope this makes more sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
MERGE INTO ppltr a USING poant b ON (a.pltr_seqn_num=b.poat_pltr_seqn_num) 
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET a.pltr_user = b.poat_user;
```

Comment: I get a ORA-30926 error unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables

Comment: You have > 1 poat_user for 1 poat_pltr_seqn_num in poant. Check this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21935340/ora-30926-unable-to-get-a-stable-set-of-rows-in-the-source-tables-when-merging

Comment: Yes, I realised that poat_pltr_seqn_num is not unique which bring out the error messages. I've resolved that now, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Correct isome minor syntax errors if it has:

```
 MERGE INTO ppltr a
   USING (SELECT poat_pltr_seqn_num, poat_user FROM poant) b
   ON (a.pltr_seqn_num = b.poat_pltr_seqn_num)
   WHEN MATCHED THEN 
     UPDATE SET a.pltr_user  = b.poat_user
   WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
     INSERT (a.pltr_seqn_num , a.pltr_user  )
     VALUES (b.poat_pltr_seqn_num, b.poat_user );
```

Comment: Thanks, I realised that poat_pltr_seqn_num is not unique in the poantemp table so the function doesn't work but I've resolved that. Decided to just do an update instead of a merge. Thanks!