# ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables - Source table don't have any records

Tags: sql, oracle, merge

I am getting ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables while merging two temp tables.

In my function, first i am inserting data into temp table temp1
and then inserting into temp2

after that doing a merge into temp1 using temp2 based on by job_id and device_id.

I am getting above error while executing function.

I have checked that tem1 has data but temp2 doesn't have any records in it .. is it the reason for this error?

Comment: It would help to show your statements, rather than pseudocode - and it's nothing to do with PL/SQL, or it being in a function, so just showing plain SQL would do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337271/ora-30926-unable-to-get-a-stable-set-of-rows-in-the-source-tables or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21935340/ora-30926-unable-to-get-a-stable-set-of-rows-in-the-source-tables-when-merging, but I'm reserving judgement until we see some code.