# Merge Fails On Oracle 19 ORA-30926

Tags: sql, oracle, merge

I need to correct some data in a table (a correclation table was messed up and therefore I need to gather the correlation data and then update another table with the information). To not mess up the production data I want to collect all the data I need into a seperate table (temptablecorrection) and then update the respective production DB tables from there.
The seperate table already has some filled rows from a previous SQL (t2.field4).

```
MERGE INTO temptablecorrection t1
USING (
          SELECT DISTINCT
              cfield1,
              cfield2,
              cfield3
          FROM
              maintable
          WHERE
              ccreationtime BETWEEN 1656396000000 AND 1656550800000
      )
t2 ON ( t1.field3 = t2.field4 )
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
SET t1.field1 = t2.field1,
    t1.field2 = t2.field2;
```

t1.field3 is unique in the timeframe (-> dinstinct count field3 and rowcount are the same).
t2.field4 is unique in the timeframe (-> dinstinct count field4 and rowcount are the same).

I get the following SQL error:

```
MERGE into dataUMCContrl t1 USING (select DISTINCT cfield1, cfield2,cfield3 from mainTable where ccrea...

ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables [SQL State=99999, DB Errorcode=30926]
1 statement failed.
```

I have no Idea what the issue is. On my testsytem the SQL works without issues.
When I checked for the issue the pointers I found were in regard to an issue with not unique rows.
But from what I gather t1.field3 and t2.field4 are unique.
In total the timeframe covers almost 74000 rows.
Any ideas to point me in the right direction?

Comment: It looks like you have multiple matches in the `using` clause. This one will help you.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21935340/ora-30926-unable-to-get-a-stable-set-of-rows-in-the-source-tables-when-merging

Comment: Perform this join and then perform count per join column to identify duplicates. Then investigate the reason

Answer (score 0):

Since field4 is unique use it in the select statement in the using clause.Also how are you using field4 in the ON clause without having field4 in the select statement

```
    MERGE INTO temptablecorrection t1
    USING (
              SELECT DISTINCT
                  cfield1,
                  cfield2,
                  cfield3,
                  field4,
                  rowid row_id 
              FROM
                  maintable
              WHERE
                  ccreationtime BETWEEN 1656396000000 AND 1656550800000
          )
    t2 ON ( t1.field3 = t2.field4 )
    WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
    SET t1.field1 = t2.cfield1,
        t1.field2 = t2.cfield2;
```

Comment: Hi, field4 is not in t1 it is in t2 only. I want to merge t2 where t1.field3 and t2.field4 are the same. I works with my test data as intended. So I must have missed something in the prod data that is not replicated in my tests.

Comment: include rowid in your select query and see if it solves the problem

Comment: Hi, I have found the reason:
One customer send files more than once. That is why there are duplicates. I have to think of a way to work around this issue.
In the end I have to do the following:
The data is based on EDI files. Each entry needs to be correlated with a second EDI file (1:1). Since a customer send a file twice the receiver also send two replies (one is then a rejection). I have to correlate now the first send file with the first reply and the second send file with the second reply file. All based on that the correlation did not happen. Thx! I will see what I can do.